# Generate every topological sort of a graph

Tags: javascript, recursion, graph-theory, topological-sort

Consider this input array which represents a graph:

```
[
    {"id":1,"prev":["NaN"]},
    {"id":2,"prev":["NaN"]},
    {"id":3,"prev":[1]},
    {"id":4,"prev":[2]},
    {"id":5,"prev":[2]},
    {"id":6,"prev":[3,4]},
    {"id":7,"prev":[5,6]}
]
```

[image]

My task is to find each possible option of ordering the elements in the list.

The order of the elements depends on whether the element has a previous one or not. For example, no. 7 will always be the last since it has 2 previous elements and no followers.

I tried to implement as follows but without success:

```
var possibleSolutions = [];
recursiveCheck(tasks.slice(), tasks.length, []);

function recursiveCheck(array, noCalls, currentSolution) {
    var solution = currentSolution;
    array.forEach((task, index, object) => {
        if (task.prev.length <= 1 && isNaN(task.prev[0])) {
            var tmpTasks = array.slice();
            solution.push(task.id);
            tmpTasks.splice(index, 1);
            tmpTasks.forEach(el => {
                el.prev.forEach((prevEl, index, object) => {
                    if (prevEl == task.id) {
                        object.splice(index, 1)
                    }
                })
            })
            noCalls--;
            if (noCalls == 0) {
                possibleSolutions.push(solution)
                solution = [];
            } else {
                recursiveCheck(tmpTasks, noCalls, solution);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This should be the output:

```
[
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [1,2,3,4,6,5,7],
    [1,2,3,5,4,6,7],
    [1,2,4,3,5,6,7],
    [1,2,4,3,6,5,7],
    [1,2,4,5,3,6,7],
    [1,2,5,3,4,6,7],
    [1,2,5,4,3,6,7],
    [1,3,2,4,5,6,7],
    [1,3,2,4,6,5,7],
    [1,3,2,5,4,6,7],
    [2,1,3,4,5,6,7],
    [2,1,3,4,6,5,7],
    [2,1,3,5,4,6,7],
    [2,1,4,3,5,6,7],
    [2,1,4,3,6,5,7],
    [2,1,4,5,3,6,7],
    [2,1,5,3,4,6,7],
    [2,1,5,4,3,6,7],
    [2,4,1,3,5,6,7],
    [2,4,1,3,6,5,7],
    [2,4,1,5,3,6,7],
    [2,4,5,1,3,6,7],
    [2,5,1,3,4,6,7],
    [2,5,1,4,3,6,7],
    [2,5,4,1,3,6,7]
]
```

As another example, the array cannot be arranged like `[1,3,6,...]` because 6 has a previous element 4 and therefore element 4 must be before 6.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired output? Should it be `[[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6, 7], [2, 5, 7]]`?

Comment: So if I understand correctly your tree contains a certain number of possible paths and every output should be a combination of these paths, with only one constraint: the respect of path order for every path?

Comment: Yes, I think you understand

Comment: Interesting and tough problem!

Comment: I think it should be solved by calling the function recursively. I also think the problem is that JavaScript functions are not asynchronous. It would be much easier if they were asynchronous. I have no idea how to solve this problem anymore, so I am looking for a logical way to implement it.

Comment: See [G4G -- all toplogical sorts of a dag](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-topological-sorts-of-a-directed-acyclic-graph/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all the solutions of topological sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066338/how-to-get-all-the-solutions-of-topological-sorting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's discuss this a bit more abstractly.

A [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Directed_graph) is the data structure we're really taking as input here. We have a set `V` of vertices/nodes and a set `E` of edges. Each edge is an ordered pair `(v1, v2)`, where `v1` and `v2` are both vertices, representing an arrow from `v1` to `v2`. Here, we're representing the graph using the "adjacency list" representation.

The task is to find all the ways to [topologically sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) this graph.

We can describe the ways to topologically sort a graph as follows:

If we want to topologically sort the empty graph (the graph with no vertices), this is easy: the only way to do it is to output the empty sorting `[]`. So the list of all ways to topologically sort the empty graph will be `[[]]`.

Now, let's consider the problem of topologically sorting a non-empty graph. Consider a sequence `s` which is a topological sort of a non-empty graph `G`. We can consider the first element of `s`, which we will call `x`, and the sequence of all the rest of the elements, which we call `s'`.

We know that `x` must be a node in `G`, and we know that `x` cannot have any predecessors in `G`. In other words, there can be no node `y` such that `(y, x)` is an edge.

We also know that `s'` must be a topological sort of `G'_x`, which is `G` but with the node `x` (and all edges connecting to it) removed.

So to get all the topological sortings of `G`, we must find all sequences with initial element `x` and remaining elements `s'`, such that `x` is an element of `G` with no predecessors and `s'` is a topological sorting of `G'_x`.

```js
const remove_node = (g, x) => 
    g.flatMap((node) => node["id"] == x ? 
                        [] : 
                        {"id": node["id"], 
                         "prev": node["prev"].filter((id) => id != x)});

const topological_sorts = (g) => 
    g.length == 0 ?
    [[]] :
    g.filter((node) => node["prev"].length == 0)
     .map((node) => node["id"])
     .flatMap((id) => 
       topological_sorts(remove_node(g, id)).map((sorting) =>
         [id].concat(sorting)));

const remove_nan = (g) => g.map((node) => 
   ({ "id" : node.id, 
     "prev": node.prev.filter((predecessor) => 
       predecessor !== "NaN") } ));

const get_answer = (g) => topological_sorts(remove_nan(g));
```

Calling `get_answer` on your graph will result in the correct answer.